# Can a service receive a package.Added intent

Tags: android, android-intent, android-service

I want to show a notification when a new package is added. and I found the code that the manifest file need! what I can't figure out is how to catch the broadcast inside my service. How can I do that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can Register an `PACKAGE_INSTALL` and `PACKAGE_ADDED` Receiver for Receiving package install and uninstall events and then Start your `Service( i.e IntentService)` from `onReceive` of Broadcast Receiver for Showing notification when a new package is added.

In Manifest.xml:

```
<receiver android:name=".PackageReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_INSTALL" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED" />
            <data android:scheme="package"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

in PackageReceiver :

```
public class PackageReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

   @Override
   public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
       if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.PACKAGE_INSTALL)) {
             //START YOUR SERVICE HERE
        } 
    }

}
```

OR you can also register an receiver dynamically in your service

```
br = new BroadcastReceiver() {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //SHOW notification here or Start Notification Service
        }
    };
    IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
    intentFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED);
    intentFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_INSTALL);
    intentFilter.addDataScheme("package");
    registerReceiver(br, intentFilter);
```

Comment: I tried the above code and I found an error. the thing is, I cannot create and add the intent filters inside the service class! is there any reason for that?

Comment: No you can  create and add the intent filters inside the service class make sure you are `imporing import android.content.IntentFilter;` package in your service

Answer (score 0):

Though the answer is already posted and will work till Android 29 or Android 10, but from Android 11 or Android 30 onwards we just need to add `<queries>` or need to add the below permission in AndroidManifest.xml file -

```
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES" />
```

It's because of there are few behavior changes in Android 11 - https://developer.android.com/training/package-visibility